# Radio button $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

How to know the value of clicked button

```
<input type="radio" name="radio">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio">No
```

php part

```
$option1= $_POST['radio'];
```

When i echo it it always say's  "ON".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give a `value` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no">No
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes_value">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="No_value">No
```

and in PHP

```
$option1 = $_POST['radio']; // "Yes_value" or "No_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Write its value in input

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" >Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="No">No
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` attribute

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" />
```

Answer (score 0):

assigned different value on the radio button.

`<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="No">No`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes">Yes 
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="No">No <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="No">No <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3">No Value
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
print_r($_GET);
```

I suggest you put this in a new file and just run it, it will help you get a deeper understanding of how the radio button work in forms.

Play around, see the difference that u get with different names, and different values.

As you can see, a radio element with no value can only be on or blank (blank wont even be set in PHP)